# Put Kohana web page in server with other apps

Tags: .htaccess, server, kohana, html

I'm trying to install a Kohana web page in a server that has another applications and I'm getting the error 'No direct access allowed'. 
When I try to go to index page I see the directory. I think that it has something to do with .htaccess file or SYSPATH, but i can't figure it out.
Someone can help me?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difficult to guess what the cause of your problem might be, but do you have a line that begins `RewriteBase` in your `.htaccess`?

If not try adding one before the `RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]` line, in the format:

`RewriteBase /directory-name-here/`

So if the directory your kohana application's in is named kohana, you want a line like:

`RewriteBase /kohana/`

Answer (score 0):

SYSPATH is defined in index.php of Kohana framework.
so make sure your .htaccess is poining to correct index file.